strptime with 01/01/0000 showing ambiguous result
In the below code I am trying to parse 01/01/0000 this seems to give different results on different machines.
Is 01/01/0000 undefined behaviour in strptime implementation?
Is it possible for strptime to return nullptr in this case on some machines?
Below is the output from local machine.
[genstor@bharath cpp]$ g++ -std=c++11 test.cpp -o test.out
[genstor@bharath cpp]$ ./test.out
0-1-1 0:0
[genstor@bharath cpp]$ cat test.cpp

#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <ctime>

int main() {
    struct tm tm{};
    std::string s("01/01/0000");
    if (strptime(s.c_str(), "%d/%m/%Y", &tm)) {
        int d = tm.tm_mday,
            m = tm.tm_mon + 1,
            y = tm.tm_year + 1900;
        std::cout << y << "-" << m << "-" << d << " "
                  << tm.tm_hour << ":" << tm.tm_min;
    }
}
genstor@bharath cpp]$ g++ -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-redhat-linux
Configured with: ../configure --prefix=/usr --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --with-bugurl=http://bugzilla.redhat.com/bugzilla --enable-bootstrap --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --enable-checking=release --with-system-zlib --enable-__cxa_atexit --disable-libunwind-exceptions --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-linker-build-id --with-linker-hash-style=gnu --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,java,fortran,ada,go,lto --enable-plugin --enable-initfini-array --disable-libgcj --with-isl=/builddir/build/BUILD/gcc-4.8.5-20150702/obj-x86_64-redhat-linux/isl-install --with-cloog=/builddir/build/BUILD/gcc-4.8.5-20150702/obj-x86_64-redhat-linux/cloog-install --enable-gnu-indirect-function --with-tune=generic --with-arch_32=x86-64 --build=x86_64-redhat-linux
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-39) (GCC)

On cpp.sh:
Code: link
Output: 1900-1-1 0:0
On Linux local machine:
Output is: 0-1-1 0:0

Why would you want to parse that? There is no year 0.

We are exposing this to user, and user input can have 01/01/0000 as we are not pre-processing. Wanted to check how it is handled, and if this can cause strptime to return nullptr. nullptr can cause some undesired results in our case.

this seems to give different results on different machines -- You should be testing on different compilers, not different machines.

Why are you still using the legacy (unsafe) "C" libraries for parsing time? You should be using the <chrono> facilities in C++. e.g. std::chrono::parse. I am really curious who or what made you use  strptime

You should probably use date parsing code you control rather than that provided by the system. My system's strptime is happy to accept Feb 31 2013.

The problem is trivially dodged by input sanitization. It depends on the purpose of your application but most of the time, dates more than ten years in the past don't matter. Which conveniently disqualifies 0.

Note that "01/01/0001" to "01/01/0099" suffer from the same issue. I suspect a buggy strptime

@PepijnKramer this is some legacy code, hence not much insight into why strptime is being used. But will chrono::parse help in this situation or will it have same undefined behaviour?

@Botje Why should the parser care whether the input is contextually correct? The parser should only care whether the input is semantically correct. Contextual verification should be done after the parser has parsed the input into a more processable structure if desired.

@PaulMcKenzie this is often the same thing. My software currently supports two platforms: the Linux build is done with g++, the Windows build is done with VisualC++. There are even two Linux builds -- a Debian and the Raspi; while both of them use g++, the Raspi appears to be a 32-bit platform so I've hit some warnings (like uint32_t obtained from a json did not "naturally" fit into a time_t anymore). So, different machines can be quite useful.

@Mestkon And yet it rejects 31/20/2013. So it clearly does more than just decoding to parts. I would understand if it did no validation, but some is unpredictable and dangerous.

@Botje %m must be in range [1, 12]. It accepts 31/02/2013 but returns 03/03/2013

@Botje It's not unpredictable, allowed values are clearly stated in the manpage: https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strptime.3.html. It doesn't verify validity of a time/date, but it does sanitize impossible inputs.

Year zero has never existed. The first day A.D. is 1/1/1.

@BharathMourya Is this precisely the same code that you are running on both machines? Because you aren't printing value of tm.tm_year, you print value of tm.tm_year + 1900, which is very much different. If strptime puts -1900 in tm.tm_year, something went horribly wrong.

Thanks @Yksisarvinen, that helps. Then I can pre-process to filter values not confined to below specification.
 otherwise specified, values in the range 69–99 refer to
years in the twentieth century (1969–1999); values in the
  range 00–68 refer to years in the twenty-first century
(2000–2068).```

@Yksisarvinen I checked again and I using exact same code on my local machine and cpp.sh

Fwiw, C++20 chrono models the proleptic Gregorian calendar in the range of years [-32767, 32767].  This includes year 0 which corresponds to 1 BC.
